# How to write a procedure to test if object exists and drop it?

Tags: oracle, database-schema

In Oracle I am trying to create PROCEDURE for delete any named object if it exists. I want to execute this query,  `select * from dba_objects where owner = 'TEST'`.  But when I create procedure I get   errors:-

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE DROPDATABASEOBJECT11(ObjName varchar2,ObjType varchar2,schemaName varchar2)
-----PROCEDURE FOR DROP ALL DATABASE OBJECTS-----
IS
 v_counter number := 0;   
begin    
  if ObjType = 'TABLE' then
    select count(*) into v_counter select * from dba_objects where object_name = upper(ObjName);
    if v_counter > 0 then          
      execute immediate 'drop table ' || ObjName || ' cascade constraints';        
    end if;   
  end if;
  end;
```

I am getting error :-

```
Error(8,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(8,41): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

So how can I use that query in procedure?

Comment: By which user is the drop statement executed? I bet it is not the TEST user. You would have to include the object's schema in the drop statement.

Comment: Qualify object name with schema name.

Comment: select count(*) into v_counter select * from dba_objects where object_name = upper(ObjName) and owner = 'TEST';

Comment: I have also tried by using above mention query but i was getting same error.

Comment: Well then maybe you are logged in as a user who does not have permissions to dba_objects. Use all_objects.

Comment: @shree  running what you showed will get ORA-00923 because of the extra `select *` in the middle, not ORA-00942.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is access to DBA_OBJECTS.  Regular users don't have privileges on DBA views.  Even if they do have access to DBA views it's often through a role, and we cannot build PL/SQL programs (or views) against dependent objects granted through a role.

Solutions are:

1. Use ALL_OBJECTS instead
2. Have an authorised user (DBA) grant privileges on DBA_OBJECTS directly to your user.

The other potential problem is that you are not restricting the query and the dynamic SQL with the schema namespace.  So, your code should look like this:

```
select count(*) into v_counter
from dba_objects 
where object_type = ObjType
and owner = upper(SchemaName)
and object_name = upper(ObjName);

if v_counter > 0 then          
  execute immediate 'drop table ' || SchemaName || '.' || ObjName
            || ' cascade constraints';        
end if;
```

Comment: Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.

Comment: You did put all of the code above into a proper procedure, right?

Comment: yes and i have put code into procedure and getting error.

Comment: @shree - you seem to have replaced the `begin` with the code APC showed. This should only replace the four lines you have inside the `if ObjType = 'TABLE' then ... end if;` section. (Or, if you want to drop other object types, that outer `if` can be removed too, but the dynamic SQL should then replace `table` with `objType`).

Comment: I have replace only query from procedure.